# How to get the grayscale pixel value for a given point (x,y) on an image?

Tags: swift, image-processing, uiimage

I have been trying to use the code below to extract the grayscale value associated with a given pixel of my image. I thought it was working but then I noticed my results were inconsistent with my image.

How can I get the correct grayscale value for a given pixel of my image at (x,y) from the 1D array that my pixelValues function returns?

I tried using index = x * width of image +y but this does not seem to be working.

```
func pixelValues(fromCGImage imageRef: CGImage?) -> (pixelValues: [UInt16]?, width: Int, height: Int)
{
    var width = 0
    var height = 0
    var pixelValues: [UInt16]?
    if let imageRef = imageRef {
        width = imageRef.width
        height = imageRef.height
        let bitsPerComponent = imageRef.bitsPerComponent
        let bytesPerRow = imageRef.bytesPerRow
        let totalBytes = height * width

        let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        var intensities = [UInt16](repeating: 0, count: totalBytes)

        let contextRef = CGContext(data: &intensities, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow: bytesPerRow, space: colorSpace, bitmapInfo: 0)
        contextRef?.draw(imageRef, in: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))

        pixelValues = intensities
    }

    return (pixelValues ,width, height)
}

//Returns grayscale value of image at pixel (x,y)
func getGrayValue(pixelValues: [UInt16], width: Int, x: Int, y: Int) -> UInt16 {
    let i = x*width + y
    return pixelValues[i]
}
```

Comment: If you need to use a `CIContext`, why to just continue using CoreImage? (I'm sure there are ways to *not* use a `CIContext` for getting a value for a pixel. Maybe faster ways too.) But using this context, turn your *CIImage* into another one - and then get the grayscale value after turning it to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation

> `index = x * width of image +y`

is off, if you are storing a 2D image in a 1D array, the correct way to access a value at [x,y] is:

`index = x + width of image * y`

Answer (score 0):

Wow.   This is not good for several reasons.

1. Why return width and height when they are passed to the code in the first place?   The calling code already has that info.
2. No need to convert the entire image to greyscale.  Convert the original RGB image to a buffer in memory.  The bytes will probably be in RGBA order depending on the method used.  Then just **accurately** calculate the position of the first byte of the pixel.  Then bytePosition is usually ( xPos * 4 ) + ( yPos * rowWidthInBytes )

If the bytes are in RGBA sequence, then bytePosition will point to the red byte.  Add that byte to the following two bytes, then divide by 3.... you now have a grey value for that pixel.  Easy as that.